# Why not always use assert?

Tags: c++

If `static_assert` is restricted to compile-time evaluations, why not always stick with `assert` if it can handle both compile-time and run-time evaluated expressions?

Comment: Its the fail early principle. If you know something is wrong, fail at that point. Why would you want to allow code to compile if you know it will crash at runtime?

Comment: @Ron How is it unclear? I mean, it directly asked "Why not always stick with assert instead of static_assert"..

Comment: @clcto  Ahhh okay - thank you :)

Comment: The question is clear! Why -1!?

Comment: Clear, but shows insufficient research and thought about the problem.

Comment: `assert()` is often compiled away to nothing in release builds and only does something in debug builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`assert(...)` is ALWAYS evaluated at runtime, of course you can call it with a compile-time evaluated expression, but you will only first see the assertion at runtime.
Sometimes you wanna make sure something only compiles when a certain `expression` is `true`, thats when you use
`static_assert(expression)` which gives a compiler error if not fulfilled.
This is in direct spirit with "fail as early as possible" (and probably hard too ;-)

Comment: Also, the runtime assert requires that the code execute in the first place.